Fetch the value from google sheet
Im having a issue when fetching the value of name of a user when he is correctly login in his account. It only shows "<?!= employeeName ?>"
Note: Im using google app script
Code.gs
function doGet(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MY_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('NAME_OF_MY_SHEET');
  var employeeName = sheet.getRange('H2').getValue(); // Fetch the name from column H, second row

  Logger.log(employeeName); // debugger

  var template;

  if (isLoggedIn()) { 
    template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('firstForm'); // This is where i want to fetch the name coming from google sheet
  } else {
    template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('loginPage');
  }

  template.employeeName = employeeName;  // Pass the fetched name to the HTML template
  template.message = ''; // Optional: Set a default message if needed
  return template.evaluate();
}

function isLoggedIn() {
  return false;
}

Heres the partial code of firstForm.html
<div id="message"></div>
<input type="text" id="recId" name="recId" value="" style="display: none">
<div class="mb-1" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
  <div class="table-divider" style="border-top: 1px solid #000;"></div>
  <label for="name" class="form-label" style="flex: 0 0 150px;">Employee Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="flex: 1;" value="<?!= employeeName ?>" disabled required>
</div>

I need to display the value of name from google sheet to google app script

By using Session
Your code is almost there it's just that we need to add var isLoggedIn = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); To see if the current user is logged.
You may try to copy and paste the code change the ** MY_SHEET_ID
** to your sheet ID to retrieve the data from H2 in your sheet.
Code:
function doGet(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MY_SHEET_ID');//.getSheetByName('NAME_OF_MY_SHEET');
  var employeeName = sheet.getRange('H2').getValue(); // Fetch the name from column H, second row

  Logger.log(employeeName); // debugger

  var template;

  //check session if current user is logged in
  var isLoggedIn = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if (!isLoggedIn) { 
      template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('loginPage');
  } else {
      template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('firstForm');
  }
  template.user = employeeName;
  template.employeeName = employeeName;  // Pass the fetched name to the HTML template
  template.message = ''; // Optional: Set a default message if needed
  return template.evaluate();
}

Sample Output:

Let me know if this works for you. I had to modify some of your existing codes as well.
Reference:

Session


It shows the value of name but it redirected to Form page, the login function is not showed also there's no css applied

@Hershey this case has been closed already. For the benefit of the community. Create another ticket concerning the login function is not showing and css.
